# InvalidDefinitionException when deserializing Kotlin class with interface

Tags: java, kotlin, jackson

I have several Kotlin data classes that implement this TypeAlias interface:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue;

public interface TypeAlias<T> {
    @JsonValue
    T getValue();
}
```

Previously, I'd been using an earlier version of Jackson and they deserialized fine. But now I'm using 2.9.9.

One class that fails to deserialize:

```
data class UserId(@NotNull private val value: EntityId) : TypeAlias<EntityId> {
    @JsonCreator(mode = JsonCreator.Mode.DELEGATING)
    constructor(value: String) : this(EntityId(value))

    override fun getValue() = value
}
```

Test for it:

```
@Test
    fun `Deserialization test`() {
        val userIdString = "\"aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\""
        mapper.readValue(userIdString, UserId::class.java)
    }
```

This test blows up with:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `UserId` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa')
```

My mapper does have the KotlinModule registered.

Note that UserId does have a JsonCreator on its secondary String constructor. The behavior makes me think that the interface is causing Jackson to not see the @JsonCreator annotation. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging in with a couple coworkers, we realized that the problem had to do with the order in which modules were being registered on the ObjectMapper. We were registering a module after the Kotlin module that tampered with the config. When we instead registered the Kotlin module after the offending module, everything worked again.

Comment: It works like a charm (no need to add annotations for all classes). I had exactly same issues. thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful!

Answer (score 2):

You need a valid Jackson config. Take a look at this example

```
@Configuration
class JacksonConfig {    
    @Bean
    fun objectMapper(): ObjectMapper {
        val objectMapper = ObjectMapper()    
        val jdk8Module = Jdk8Module().configureAbsentsAsNulls(true)
        objectMapper.registerModule(jdk8Module)
        objectMapper.registerModule(JavaTimeModule())
        // ... your customizations
        objectMapper.registerKotlinModule()
        return objectMapper
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used 2.9.9 with the below code and i was able to deserialize. (Sorry about putting this in the answer block, couldnt format it right in the comments section)

```
data class abc( private val value: def?)  {

    @JsonCreator(mode =JsonCreator.Mode.DELEGATING)
    constructor( s: String) : this(def(s)) {
        println(s)
    }

}

data class def(val data: String)

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Hello World!")
    val m: ObjectMapper =  ObjectMapper()
    m.readValue("\"5abc\"", abc::class.java)
}
```

could you post a git link to a simple repo where we could reproduce the issue?

Comment: Thanks Arpan. I see that there's not an interface being used here, though? I'm able to deserialize if I don't use an interface. As far as the repo goes, it's an internal company repo so I'm not able to share it.

Comment: I used an interface and i still dont get the error.. Below is the code.. Sorry about the formatting

Comment: fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val m: ObjectMapper =  ObjectMapper()
//    m.readValue("\"5abc\"", abc::class.java)
    val user = m.readValue("\"5abc\"", UserId::class.java)
    println(user.getValue())
}

 interface TypeAlias<T> {

    @JsonValue
    fun getValue(): T
}

data class UserId(private val value: EntityId) : TypeAlias<EntityId> {
    @JsonCreator(mode = JsonCreator.Mode.DELEGATING)
    constructor(value: String) : this(EntityId(value)) {
        println(value)
    }

    override fun getValue() = value
}

data class EntityId(val value: String)

Comment: Thanks. You're right, it works with an interface. After digging in with a couple coworkers, we realized that the problem had to do with registering a module after the Kotlin module that tampered with the config. When we bound the Kotlin module afterwards, everything worked again.

Comment: Thanks again for your help!